# What is a good way to store color?

Tags: c++, colors

I started to make "game of life" and I thought, what if I could have more states than 1 or 0.

But then I need different colors. I want the colors to be linked to a grid/object (the grid is a class).

What is a good/decent way to store color pallets for fast/easy access?

My current less than ideal solution was to have 4 pointers to memory for each red, green, blue and alpha value.

In my class I had a function to set the color of value `v` to rgba:

```
SetColor(v, r, g, b, a) //Set v to the appropriate color values
```

I would like to keep this function to easily modify a color.

Comment: "easily modify"? what the problem with the current implementation?

Comment: its very messy and uses excessive memory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I use is something really simple: 4 floats

```
struct Color {
    float r, g, b, a;
};
```

Then, you can have something like a color pallete:

```
// a Palette of 8 colors:
using palette_t = std::array<Color, 8>

palette_t myPalette { /* ... */ };
```

Then, in your grid or object class, you can reference the color with an index:

```
struct Grid {
    // lot's of code

private:
    std::size_t colorIndex = 0;
};
```

---

But then you asked how to have easy access to the color (I guess the easy access is from within the `Grid` class)

There is a lot of solution that can exists, and most will depend of your project structure. This is one idea many others. I hope it will inspire you.

You can store a function that return the right color:

```
struct Grid {
    // lot's of code

private:
    std::size_t colorIndex = 0;
    std::function<Color(std::size_t)> color;
};
```

And then, have something that create your grid correctly:

```
struct GridCreator {
    GridCreator(const palette_t& aPalette) : palette{aPalette} {}

    Grid create(std::size_t color) const {
        Grid grid;

        // create the grid

        grid.color = [this](std::size_t index) {
            return palette[index];
        };

        return grid;
    }

private:
    const palette_t& palette;
};
```

Then you got free access to your color palette without directly knowing that the palette exists from the `Grid` class.

Comment: is std::array extendable or fixed?

Comment: The purpose of `std::array` is to have an array with a size known at compile-time. You won't be able to resize it at runtime. However, when you  already know the size and you don't intend to change it during runtime, `std::array` is the right choice. btw it's much much lighter than a vector ;)

Comment: then i probably go for a vector of size 256.

Comment: btw, how would i limit the size of the color values to 1 byte

Comment: That's out of the scope of this question. You may feel free to ask a question about optimizing the size of the color struct.

Comment: i know but the question would be so short and this question is partially about saving space storing colors

Comment: "btw, how would i limit the size of the color values to 1 byte" @Kriso: just use `uint8_t` as grid type? So all your grid values can be only 0..255, whatever you would try to put there.

Comment: i tried uint8_t once but had some problems. is it initiated the same as regular int?

Comment: @Kriso I don't understand your question, `uint8_t` is POD (Plain Old Data) type (like `int`), so it's [un]initialized in the exactly same way as `int`. You can have problems to display it with iostream, which will treat it as `char` (use `0xFF&value` to convert it to `int`), but that's not hampering any arithmetic code, only formatting of output. You have to post the actual problem, sorry.

Comment: @Ped7g i was asking if i could use uint8_t the same way as int. the answer appeared to be yes

Comment: @Kriso: then again, using only 8 bit value may have some additional traps for beginners, like this infinite `for` loop: `for (uint8_t i = 0; i != 256; ++i) (true);` ... but it's a good lesson, and your debugger surely works.. ;) | edit: yes, `uint8_t` is as good (and bad) as `int` type, acting the same way, but being only 8 bit "wide".

Comment: And your feeling about `union { struct {a,r,g,b}; uint32_t color}` which gives access to each component and forms a full 32 bits color?

Comment: @Sandburg technically undefined behavior. I would rather add a function `color()` that reconstruct the `uint32_t`.

Answer (score 4):

Have an array of colors:

```
std::vector<std::array<unsigned char, 4>> palette {
    {255, 0, 0, 255},  // red
    {0, 255, 0, 255},  // green
    {0, 0, 255, 255},  // blue
};
```

Then for each field store the index in the array (of type `size_t`). Example:

```
auto id = field[5][2];
auto color = palette[id];
auto r = color[0], alpha = color[3];
```

Changing a color is as simple as:

```
palette[id] = {255, 0, 0, 127};
```

For adding new colors, use:

```
palette.push_back({255, 0, 0, 127}).
```

Alternatively, you can define a simple struct so that you can use `color.r`, `color.alpha` etc. and write a constructor for easy color creation.

Mind this example is C++11 code.

Comment: great, so how would i extend it during runtime

Comment: @Kriso: back in the stone age, when computers were from bones and leather, we used uint32_t (`0x12345678` = 0x12 alpha, 0x34 red, 0x56 green, 0x78 blue). I believe most of the graphical APIs still support this ARGB 32b format. Then you can use `std::vector<uint32_t> palette;` to store palette. Also you may check some articles about gifs, to see 256 indexed palette mode in action, how it was done. Ypnos variant with std::array<uint8_t, 4> is basically the very same thing, with just some additional syntax sugar on top (making it a tiny bit easier to access particular channel value).

Comment: @Kriso this format is usually 1:1 how the HW treats 32b "true color" graphic modes, so another benefit is performance, the color value can be used directly in gfx driver API without conversion. In 256 color indexed mode this structure works well too. Although I think some modern 3D APIs have some special limited float definition natively too, but unless you go into HDR + lot of transparency rendering, it would hardly benefit you.

Comment: @ypnos i wish i could accept 2 answers because this answerd half my queston and the other the other half. i thought you should know

Answer (score 1):

Enums are perfect for Colors kind of structure.

1. More code readability.
2. Better compiler-time optimizations.

   ```
   enum Color { red, green, blue };
   Color r = red;
   switch(r)
   {
       case red  : std::cout << "red\n";   break;
       case green: std::cout << "green\n"; break;
       case blue : std::cout << "blue\n";  break;
   }
   ```

For your special case.
You can store color for each point as a single integer.

```
uint32_t point_color = field[5][2].color;
unsigned char* color = (unsigned char*)point_color[id];
auto r = color[0], alpha = color[3];

///// 

void SetColor(uint32_t& point_color,unsigned char r,
               unsigned char g,unsigned char b,unsigned char a){
   point_color=r | (b*(1<<8)) | (g*(1<<16)) | (a*(1<<24));   
}
```

Pros of this structure

1. lesser messy.
2. faster bit operations only.
3. lesser memory.

Comment: A `enum class` is better than an `enum`, consider using that instead.

Comment: i don't think you got my question. i need to access colors from a list based on a value/ID.

Comment: No, @Kriso, You can still sore it in ENUMs.

Comment: so how would i define 256 colors during runtime

Comment: @Krisu You can use a 4D vector

Comment: @Rakete1111 are they extendable? like if it start at 10, can i then increase the size to 20

Comment: @Kriso What do you mean? You can always make a dynamic array of 4D vectors

Comment: @Rakete1111 but you cannot extend an enum at runtime.

Comment: @ypnos But I never said that. My suggestion is to use an array of 4D vectors, with no enums involved

Answer (score 0):

Your question is dualistic:

- What is a good way to store color?
- what is a good/decent way to store color pallets?

If you really only want to store a colour, my advise would be not to store the colours as references, but to store the RGB values in one INT32 inside a class where you can get and set the Reg / Green / Blue values. Compare this with how .NET does this.

The advantage of this method is that it does no more space than using pointers and it is fast in get / set / comparisons.

A color pallette is a collection of colours. This is quite often used if you want to switch all used colours into a different colour. For instance if you want all light-blue colours in to misty-blue colours, and all fire-red colours into brick-red.

This is used by defining a palette as a pre-defined sized array or RGB values. Historically a palette contains 16, 64, or 256 values, or sometimes 2 if you only want black/white pictures.
If you use a palette, every dot in your grid has an index in your palette array and your grid has a current pallette. The RGB value of point X of grid G is then G.CurrentPallette[X.PaletIndex]. Changing all colours of your grid at once means switching to a different palette: G.CurrentPalette = otherPalette. This is a really fast and efficient way of changing the colours in your grid

Whether to use the RGB method or the Palette method depends on what you want:

- Do you only want to use a subset of all possible colours, and do you want to change the complete subset into a different subset: use the Palette method
- Do you want to change the colour of dots with a certain state, for instance change all yellow dots to green, use the palette method: change the color yellow  in your palette to green
- However, if you only want to change individual dots on your grid it is probably more efficient to use the RGB method.

Answer (score 0):

any color value has an interval from 0 through 255 so you need 3 unsigned char variables and another one for alph. we make a whole thing, mapping them an a struct:

```
typedef struct Color
{
    unsigned char _ucRed;
    unsigned char _ucGreen;
    unsigned char _ucBlue;
    unsigned char _ucAlpha;
}COLOR;
```